# Return the zero value while creating view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

[image: 1]

How can I use inner join to create view in SQL Server as shown in RECAPITULATION TABLE. I want the code with unsold out is also shown with 0 value? Using INNER JOIN statement, it just select the C001, C002, C005 and C007. But, I want to show C003, C004, and C006 with 0 value as well.

Comment: In addition to noting, please update your question.

Comment: And even better than tabular data is DDL+DML that people can copy and paste out to test your query.

Comment: @DaleK I know what your thought. But I also consider, typing data tabular in Editor is really BAD PRACTICE consume much time and also not accurate. If you want the people create the data tabular directly on the web, please provide the feature just like excel on this form, so it make easy to post multi tables in the next time. Thank you

Comment: Just as you don't want to type data into the question, we don't want to transcribe data out of screen shots. If you'd like people to help you with questions like this then don't put up roadblocks. Make it as easy as possible for people to copy-paste code and data into SSMS, dbfiddle, etc., so that they're inclined to help you. For tips, see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @PhilipsTel 1) I don't make the rules or the editor for this site - its a site rule to not use images 2) Why do you think it was me that downvoted you? 3) My guess is you have been downvoted due to lack of attempt - another site rule (not mine) is that you need to have a go and show us. 4) Its in your own best interest to make it as easy as possible for people to answer, and the best thing you can do to help us, is provide a [mre] which includes sample data in a form we can copy and paste out DDL+DML is best, but well formatted tabular data is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple left join and aggregation will do what you want. As an example, aggregate your transaction table in a CTE and then left join from your inventory table to the cte. That will cause a row to appear in your resultset for every row in inventory. You can replace NULL values with zero - a task I leave to you

```
with cte as (
   select INV_CODE, sum([SOLD_OUT]) as TOTAL 
   from dbo.[TRANSACTION LOG] group by INV_CODE
)
select inv.INV_CODE, cte.TOTAL 
from dbo.[INVENTORY TABLE] as inv
left join cte on inv.INV_CODE = cte.INV_CODE
order by ...;
```

Not certain why you focus on "inner join" since that is not an obvious path to your goal.